# Error Updating Nodes in Neo4J via Rest

Tags: neo4j

We have a Neo4J test database with approximately 2.5 million nodes.  We are attempting to update every node to include some additional properties.  To accomplish this, we are using the REST API to update each node in turn.

About halfway through the process, we receive an out of memory error response from the server, and the following stack trace is returned in the REST response:

```
    {
      "message" : "java.io.IOException: Map failed",
      "exception" : "RuntimeException",
      "fullname" : "java.lang.RuntimeException",
      "stacktrace" : [
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.refreshSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:514)",
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.refreshSearcherIfNeeded(LuceneDataSource.java:631)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.getIndexSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:575)",
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:268)", "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.get(LuceneIndex.java:207)",
    "org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractAutoIndexerImpl$ReadOnlyIndexToIndexAdapter.get(AbstractAutoIndexerImpl.java:236)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.indexGet(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:84)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$1.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:76)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$1.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:73)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:36)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:35)", 
    "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)",
    "scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)",
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)",
    "scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:178)",
    "scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)",
    "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:259)",
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:243)", 
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toList(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.EagerPipe.internalCreateResults(EagerPipe.scala:35)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:69)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$executionplan$ExecutionPlanImpl$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:164)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:146)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:145)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.execute(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:38)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:72)",
    "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:76)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:79)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:94)", 
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.extension.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:57)" 

    ],
      "cause" : {
        "message" : "Map failed",
        "cause" : {
          "message" : "Map failed",
          "exception" : "OutOfMemoryError",
          "stacktrace" : [ 
    "sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)", 
    "sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:846)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput.(MMapDirectory.java:270)",
    "org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:220)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.openInput(FSDirectory.java:345)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.CompoundFileWriter.copyFile(CompoundFileWriter.java:231)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.CompoundFileWriter.close(CompoundFileWriter.java:201)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flush(DocumentsWriter.java:604)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3587)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3552)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:450)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:399)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(DirectoryReader.java:413)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:432)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:375)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:392)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.openIfChanged(IndexReader.java:634)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.refreshSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:503)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.refreshSearcherIfNeeded(LuceneDataSource.java:631)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.getIndexSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:575)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:268)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.get(LuceneIndex.java:207)", 
    "org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractAutoIndexerImpl$ReadOnlyIndexToIndexAdapter.get(AbstractAutoIndexerImpl.java:236)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.indexGet(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:84)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$1.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:76)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$1.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:73)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:36)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:35)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)", 
    "scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)", 
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)", 
    "scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:178)", 
    "scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)", 
    "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:259)", 
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:243)", 
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toList(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.EagerPipe.internalCreateResults(EagerPipe.scala:35)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:69)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$executionplan$ExecutionPlanImpl$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:164)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:146)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:145)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.execute(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:38)", "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:72)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:76)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:79)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:94)", 
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.extension.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:57)" 
    ],
          "fullname" : "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"
        },
        "exception" : "IOException",
        "stacktrace" : [ 
    "sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:849)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput.(MMapDirectory.java:270)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:220)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.openInput(FSDirectory.java:345)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.CompoundFileWriter.copyFile(CompoundFileWriter.java:231)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.CompoundFileWriter.close(CompoundFileWriter.java:201)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flush(DocumentsWriter.java:604)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3587)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3552)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:450)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:399)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(DirectoryReader.java:413)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:432)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:375)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:392)", 
    "org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.openIfChanged(IndexReader.java:634)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.refreshSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:503)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.refreshSearcherIfNeeded(LuceneDataSource.java:631)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.getIndexSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:575)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:268)", 
    "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.get(LuceneIndex.java:207)", 
    "org.neo4j.kernel.AbstractAutoIndexerImpl$ReadOnlyIndexToIndexAdapter.get(AbstractAutoIndexerImpl.java:236)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.indexGet(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:84)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$1.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:76)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$1.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:73)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:36)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:35)", 
    "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)", 
    "scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)", 
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)", 
    "scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:178)", 
    "scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)", 
    "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:259)", 
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:243)", 
    "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toList(Iterator.scala:1156)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.EagerPipe.internalCreateResults(EagerPipe.scala:35)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:69)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$executionplan$ExecutionPlanImpl$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:164)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:146)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:145)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.execute(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:38)", "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:72)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:76)", 
    "org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:79)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:94)", 
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", 
    "org.neo4j.server.extension.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:57)" 
    ],
        "fullname" : "java.io.IOException"
      }
    }
```

I have also included an example of our request content and headers:

```
    JSON content:
    {"query":"START myNode=node:node_auto_index(myIndex = {myIndex}) SET myNode.propOne = {propOne}, myNode.propTwo = {propTwo}, myNode.propThree = {propThree}","params":{"propOne":"valueOne","propTwo":"valueTwo","propThree":"valueThree","myIndex":"indexValue"}}

    Request Headers:
    POST /db/data/cypher HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:7474
    Accept: application/json
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length:
```

neo4j-wrapper.conf

```
    wrapper.java.additional=-Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties
    wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties
    wrapper.java.additional=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties

    #********************************************************************
    # JVM Parameters
    #********************************************************************

    wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
    wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

    # Uncomment the following lines to enable garbage collection logging
    #wrapper.java.additional=-Xloggc:data/log/neo4j-gc.log
    #wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCDetails
    #wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
    #wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime

    # Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
    wrapper.java.initmemory=2048

    # Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
    wrapper.java.maxmemory=8192

    #********************************************************************
    # Wrapper settings
    #********************************************************************
    # Override default pidfile and lockfile 
    #wrapper.pidfile=../data/neo4j-server.pid
    #wrapper.lockfile=../data/neo4j-server.lck

    #********************************************************************
    # Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
    #********************************************************************
    # WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
    #  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
    #  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
    #  service can then be reinstalled.

    # Name of the service
    wrapper.name=neo4j

    # User account to be used for linux installs. Will default to current
    # user if not set.
    wrapper.user=neo4j

    wrapper.user.created=false
```

neo4j.properties

```
    # Default values for the low-level graph engine
    neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=100M
    neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=2G
    neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
    neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=250M
    neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M

    # Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from 1.4 -> 1.5 or 1.4 -> 1.6
    #allow_store_upgrade=true

    # Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one. 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 are available
    #cypher_parser_version=1.6

    # Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
    # legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
    # as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true"
    keep_logical_logs=true

    # Autoindexing

    # Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
    node_auto_indexing=true

    # The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
    node_keys_indexable=user_id,group_id,program_id

    # Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
    #relationship_auto_indexing=true

    # The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
    #relationship_keys_indexable=name,age
```

PLEASE READ VERY CAREFULLY:
I am not necessarily looking for alternative methods for updating our Node properties.  I am actually very confident that we could easily come up with something that works around this error.  My purpose in posting this question is to better understand the nature of this error.  What exactly is causing it in the first place?  My hope is that understanding the cause of this error would better help us to avoid it in a production environment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sending the requests in parallel? If so, how many parallel requests are sent out?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Requests are not being executed in parallel in this particular case.  All requests are executed in sequence.

Comment: Are you executing this via the WebAdmin - it seems so from the stack trace? In that case, it could be that the messages are not using the streaming REST endpoints, and thus run into serialization problems in the JSON layer.

Comment: could you post the URL and a sample payload of your REST request? As Peter said, that stacktrace shouldn't have all the webadmin stuff in it, if you're doing what you're saying you are

Comment: @MichalBachman, much thanks to both you and Peter for your comments.  You are absolutely correct, that error does appear to be from our webadmin console, and therefore is not related to the error we're seeing in our REST requests.  I apparently grabbed the wrong error from the log.  Sorry for the confusion, but I have now updated my post to reflect the actual error message and stack trace, received in response to our REST request.  Per your request, I have also included an example of our request content.  Please take a look again and let me know your thoughts.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: ok, could you please also post the contents of your neo4j-wrapper.conf and neo4j.properties? They're in the /conf/ directory of your Neo4j server installation

Comment: @MichalBachman Thank you for your continued assistance.  Per your request, I have posted copies of the two configuration files.